# Webview postUrl , loading animation issue in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

i am trying to post data using `postUrl` method on `webview`. 
I want to make loading `animation` during posting url. But loading animation does not start immediately, it waits couple of seconds and then starts animation.

Here is my code ;

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", GeneralConstants.TEXT_LOADING, false);
dialog.startLoadingAnimation();
webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

Thanks for any idea , regards.